# How to add padding to scrollTop() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have a parent div with a list of div's.
In parrent div I also added fixed positioned div on the top of parent div.
Based on some action I call:

```
$('#parent').animate({       
                    scrollTop: $("#" + itemId).offset().top  - $('#parent').offset().top + $('#parent').scrollTop()
                     }, 500);
```

This successfully scroll to a div and put it on the top.
The issue is that when searched div is on the top I can't see it because it is bellow fixed div.

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="fixedDiv" style="position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
background: #000;
width: 300px;">
... some elements ...
</div>
<ul>
... list of divs...
</div>
```

Is there some solution to scroll to div padded from the top of parent?

Comment: Just substract height of fixed div to a scrollTop declration ( - 100 at end of line to start with). Should do the trick :)

Comment: No, it still goes bellow it :(

Comment: Or - $('#fixedDiv').height()

Comment: Yeah... math  :-) add the answer please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- $('#fixedDiv').height()
```

at end of scrollTop line will do :)

Answer (score 25):

This is what I use, for a smooth scroll with 10px of upper padding:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#div').offset().top-10},1000);
```